# How do you display the date without the time using a DateTime value in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a datetime variable in my application. Its value is 01/09/2010 00:00:00. I want to get value of 01/09/2010. Still I want to use the DateTime structure. Is there any method/property for that. I know it is possible using conversion. 
For example I have
DateTime date = new DateTime(2010,09,01);
It will display 01/09/2010 00:00:00

I want date to be 01/09/2010 alone.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `date.ToShortDateString()` so see only the date part of the `DateTime` object.

To force a specific format (if that is not your default culture format), you can use

date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Note that Im not sure if `01` or `09` is the month in your example. If I have mixed them up, just replace `"dd/MM/yyyy"` with `"MM/dd/yyyy"`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a way to format the date for display/printing purposes, or to get rid of the time part if it is given?

Use the `DateTime.ToShortDateString()` method or the `DateTime.Date` property, respectively.