# Force DateTime variable to display only the Date without converting ToString()

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I've got an object property, `DateTime Date`. I'm trying to keep this as a `DateTime` object, but display ONLY the date, i.e. `9/30/2013`. I do not want to use a `ToString()` or `ToShortDateString()`. I have tried using `Date.Date`, but this still shows the date and time. Is there any way to view the date of a `DateTime` without converting it to a string?

I've also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246314/how-do-you-display-the-date-without-the-time-using-a-datetime-value-in-c). The question is worded the way I'd like, but the answers still use a `ToShortDateString()`.

This will be displayed in a `DataGrid` that is bound to my object.

Comment: You say you want to "display only the date" - where is this being displayed?

Comment: How are you going to "display" your datetime without converting it to string?

Comment: @ReedCopsey: It's being displayed in a `DataGrid` that is bound to my object.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Aye. Editing tags to reflect this.

Comment: DateTime is data type and not viewed, controls display dates by formatting them to a string, as far as I know this is always true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `DateTime`, by definition, will always have values for the date and the time.  You can convert it to another `DateTime` representing the date portion (with a time of Midnight) via `DateTime.Date`.

However, in order to display the `DateTime` in a control, it will always be converted to a string.  The best option is typically to try to control how that conversion occurs in your `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TheDate, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This will cause the column bound to "TheDate" to use a custom string format when displaying your `DateTime`.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I'm still learning the ins and outs of WPF, and this `StringFormat`. Oh my god, it's going to save my sanity. I had gathered that it was converting it to string for display, but was unaware how to format it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `string.Format()`:

```
var date = new DateTime(2013, 09, 30);
string.Format("{0:dd MM yyyy}", date); // 09 30 2013
```